# Programmatically append some td to tr - jQuery AJAX JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I've been looking for some way to append td to tr to table using jQuery without knowing anything about my json response, at this point in time I've reached this:

```
function getClientes(){
    $.ajax({
    url:URL_BASE+"Cliente",
    type:"GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("hola" + ":" + "hola"));
    },
    success: function (data){
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                $('<tr>').append(
                    $.each(value,function(value,celda)
                    {
                        $('<td>').text(celda);
                    })                      
            ).appendTo('#table');
            })
        }
    });     
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting my .html output like this:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-condensed">
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
</table>
```

So this is not appending the td to the tr, I do not want to append them mannually I know it is very easy to do it but this is way better for me, please help :D

Comment: `return $('<td>').text(celda);`?

Comment: append with an each inside makes no sense. The each does not return anything. If you mapped and returned a collection of elements it would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this::

```
function getClientes(){
    $.ajax({
    url:URL_BASE+"Cliente",
    type:"GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("hola" + ":" + "hola"));
    },
    success: function (data){
            $.each(data,function(index,value){
                $('tr').append(
                    $.each(value,function(value,celda)
                    {
                        $('td').text(celda);
                    })                      
            ).appendTo('#table');
            })
        }
    });     
}
```

I think it will work.

Comment: That only changes that tr does not apeear too.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to append your data like below first creating a table row and then appending to the last table row using selector `$('tr:last')`

```js
var data = [["hello", "A"], ["hiii", "B"], ["hey", "C"]]


 $.each(data,function(index,value){
              $("#table").append('<tr></tr>') 
                     $.each(value,function(value,celda)
                    {
                       $('tr:last').append('<td>' + celda + '</td>');
                    })                   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-condensed">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Pen: http://codepen.io/rarmatei/pen/XpYWNL

I used the array "map" operator instead of jQuery's $.each.

In your function, when you  do `$('<td>').text(celda);` inside each $.each() interation, the VM simply executes this instruction without storing/returning the result to be added to the final set of generated HTML elements.

So your function might look something like the below:

```js
function getClientes() {
  $.ajax({
    url: URL_BASE + "Cliente",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("hola" + ":" + "hola"));
    },
    success: function(data) {
      data.map(value => {
        var elements = value.map(subValue => {
          return $('<td>').text(subValue);
        });
        return $('<tr>').append(elements);
      }).appendTo('#table');
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I created a row and append it manually in each loop, not the best answer but it works for me, thank you for all answers :D

```
function getClientes(){
$.ajax({
url:URL_BASE+"Cliente",
type:"GET",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("hola" + ":" + "hola"));
},
success: function (data){
        $.each(data,function(index,value){
        var row = $("<tr/>");                

                $.each(value,function(value,celda)
                {
                   row.append($('<td>').text(celda));
                });                      
        $('#table').append(row);
        })
    }
});     
}
```