# jQuery append td to dynamically created tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a table and I'd like to append a row with multiple `td` to it:

```
var $tblBody = $('#' + btn.attr('data-tbody-id')); //tbody of the Table

// Append the Row
$tblBody.append('<tr id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');
var $tblRow = $('<tr id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');

//Loop through my data and append tds
$.each(data.extra.fields, function (i, v) {
    console.log(i); //Shows 0,1,2,3 etc. 
    $tblRow.append('' +
         '<td class="' + v.cellClass + '">' +
         '   <span class="'+data.extra.span+'_'+v.name+'_'+data.extra.id+'">' + v.value + '</span>' +
         '</td>'
    )
});
```

Unfortunately the created to stays empty:

`<tr id="row_ZWxoQXArUi82K3BjaFY4Y0x2ZWR3UT09_41_temp"></tr>`

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040692/1092632 but why is the above not working for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make the `td`s of the row, after that append whole `tr` to the body.

Remove this line

`$tblBody.append('<tr id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');`,

because you don't have a reference on it and use `append` part of your code after the loop.

```
var $tblRow = $('<tr id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');

$.each(data.extra.fields, function (i, v) {
    console.log(i); //Shows 0,1,2,3 etc. 
    $tblRow.append('' +
         '<td class="' + v.cellClass + '">' +
         '   <span class="'+data.extra.span+'_'+v.name+'_'+data.extra.id+'">' + v.value + '</span>' +
         '</td>'
    )
});

$tblBody.append($tblRow); // <-----------------------
```

Comment: smooth, simple, and most importantly answered faster than it took to phrase the question! Thank you, can accept in 7 minutes

Comment: @PrimuS glad to help you. Thank you too

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
var $tblRow = $('<tr id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');
```

creates a new reference which is not in DOM yet.

instead, replace it with this

```
var $tblRow = $tblBody.find( "#row_' + data.extra.span + '_' + data.extra.id + '_temp">');
```

This will now get you the handle to the same row which has already been appended to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Here you with one more solution using `ES6 template literals`

```
var $tblBody = $('#' + btn.attr('data-tbody-id')); //tbody of the Table

// Append the Row
var rowid = 'row_' + data.extra.span + '_' + data.extra.id + '_temp';
$tblBody.append(`<tr id=${rowid} />`);

//Loop through my data and append tds
$.each(data.extra.fields, function (i, v) {
  console.log(i); //Shows 0,1,2,3 etc. 
  $(`#${rowid}`).append(
     `<td class="${v.cellClass}">
       <span class="${data.extra.span}_${v.name}_${data.extra.id}">
         ${v.value}
       </span>
     </td>`);
});
```

Once you appended the `tr` then use the id instead of get the row & appending the `td`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

change the code to something like this

```
var $tblBody = $('#' + btn.attr('data-tbody-id')); //tbody of the Table

// Append the Row
$tblBody.append('<tr id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp"></tr>');
var $tblRow = $('#'+'row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp');

//Loop through my data and append tds
$.each(data.extra.fields, function (i, v) {
    console.log(i); //Shows 0,1,2,3 etc. 
    $tblRow.append('' +
         '<td class="' + v.cellClass + '">' +
         '   <span class="'+data.extra.span+'_'+v.name+'_'+data.extra.id+'">' + v.value + '</span>' +
         '</td>'
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append `tblRow` to the `tblBody`. Adding the last line would fix your code

```
// Append the Row
$tblBody.append('<tr 
id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');
var $tblRow = $('<tr 
id="row_'+data.extra.span+'_'+data.extra.id+'_temp">');

//Loop through my data and append tds
$.each(data.extra.fields, function (i, v) {
    console.log(i); //Shows 0,1,2,3 etc. 
    $tblRow.append('' +
         '<td class="' + v.cellClass + '">' +
         '   <span 
class="'+data.extra.span+'_'+v.name+'_'+data.extra.id+'">' + v.value + 
'</span>' +
     '</td>'
    )
});

$tblBody.append($tblRow);
```